# Silverlight Binding issue in a Style

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I'm trying to bind a setter value to a property but I keep getting Catastrophic errors 0x8000ffff

Tried this:

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Style>
```

Then this:

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                Value="0" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Style>
```

I had to upgrade to SL5 to get the TargetType. The second example removes any attempt to bind but still fails "Catastrophically".

> ```
> <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
>     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
>         <layout:MatrixGrid />
>     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
> </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
> ```

I'm trying to create a matrix of data in a grid (as described in an example by someone else).

ItemsControl (in Silverlight) has no ItemContainerStyle element so I'm trying this, no luck so far.

> ```
> <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
>     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
>         <layout:MatrixGrid />
>     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
> </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
> <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
>     <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
>         <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
>                 Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
>         <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
>                 Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
>     </Style>
> </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
> ```

Comment: Can you show the context of where you are using this style.

Comment: Hi ChrisF, I'm using this in an ItemsControl

Comment: Why are you using TargetType="ContentPresenter" if your style is to `ItemsControl`?

Comment: I lost it in translation, started off with a WPF example which had <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">

Answer (score 0):

[Style.TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Property sets the type for which the style is intended. Try to set it to `ItemsControl`, that is probably the reason why it falls.